# cant get a value in DataKeys to show up in Response.Write asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with checkboxes which I want to capture to know the row that is checked. The problem is that the code doesn't seem to get past the condition of the checkboxes controls being checked. I have put the checkboxes in a template to get them to work, and I called the control `addCart` 
Now I have the following code:

```
protected void addCart_HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow fila in GridCol.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox addCart = (CheckBox)fila.FindControl("addCart");
                if (addCart.Checked)
            {Response.Write(GridCol.DataKeys[fila.RowIndex].Value + "Cantidad: " + fila.Cells[3].Text);
                rowSel.Text = GridCol.DataKeys[fila.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

But although when I debug I can see that the Checked value of `addCart` changes to true, nothing displays. I wonder if I'm using Response.Write incorrectly, but I think still the label `rowSel`should show something, yet nothing happens. I'm trying to verify that the code actually works so I can pass the row value later. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
for (int i = 0; i < YourGridViewID.Rows.Count; i++)
{

 GridViewRow row = YourGridView.Rows[i];
 bool isChecked = ((CheckBox) row.FindControl("yourCheckBoxID")).Checked;

  if (isChecked)
  {
    Response.Write((string)this.YourGridViewID.DataKeys[i]["yourColumnDataKey"];);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your code, though I realized today I was calling the values that were supposed to go into the list I have to populate the GridView, from the wrong class! That was really part of the problem because I got an error telling me the value of the key was infinite. After those corrections, everything was fine, and I didn't bother to use a foreach loop as I did before, though I think it wouldn't make a difference, after all, but thank you for caring to answer. I was a bit desperate and I didn't check my code thoroughly before posting, but hey, sh... happens!